# Server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client - Hashicorp Vault

Tags: kubernetes, hashicorp-vault

I'm having trouble enabling TLS communication between the vault-agent proxy/sidecar and the Vault server, both located in a Kubernetes cluster. The error message I receive on the client side is:

```
[ERROR] auth.handler: error authenticating: error="Put "https://vault.vault.svc:8200/v1/auth/kubernetes/login\": http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client" backoff=4m6.44s
```

This error also occurs when I execute commands within the sidecar container, such as vault login, with VAULT_ADDR set to https://vault.vault.svc:8200.

I'm deploying Vault using the Helm Chart with the following values:

```
global:
  tlsDisable: false
ui:
  enabled: true
server:
  extraEnvironmentVars:
    VAULT_CACERT: /vault/userconfig/vault-server-tls-secret/ca.crt
    VAULT_TLSCERT: /vault/userconfig/vault-server-tls-secret/tls.crt
    VAULT_TLSKEY: /vault/userconfig/vault-server-tls-secret/tls.key
  extraVolumes:
    - type: secret
      name: vault-server-tls-secret
  logLevel: "debug"
  ha:
    enabled: true
    nodes: 3
    replicas: 3
    raft:
      enabled: true
      setNodeId: true
      config: |
        ui = true

        listener "tcp" {
          tls_disable = 0
          tls_cert_file = "/vault/userconfig/vault-server-tls-secret/tls.crt"
          tls_key_file  = "/vault/userconfig/vault-server-tls-secret/tls.key"
          tls_client_ca_file = "/vault/userconfig/vault-server-tls-secret/ca.crt"
          address = "[::]:8200"
          cluster_address = "[::]:8201"
        }

        storage "raft" {
          path = "/vault/data"

          retry_join {
            leader_api_addr = "https://vault-0.vault-internal:8200"
            leader_tls_servername = "vault-0.vault-internal"
            leader_ca_cert_file = "/vault/userconfig/vault-server-tls-secret/ca.crt"
            leader_client_cert_file = "/vault/userconfig/vault-server-tls-secret/tls.crt"
            leader_client_key_file = "/vault/userconfig/vault-server-tls-secret/tls.key"
          }

          retry_join {
            leader_api_addr = "https://vault-1.vault-internal:8200"
            leader_tls_servername = "vault-0.vault-internal"
            leader_ca_cert_file = "/vault/userconfig/vault-server-tls-secret/ca.crt"
            leader_client_cert_file = "/vault/userconfig/vault-server-tls-secret/tls.crt"
            leader_client_key_file = "/vault/userconfig/vault-server-tls-secret/tls.key"
          }

          retry_join {
            leader_api_addr = "https://vault-2.vault-internal:8200"
            leader_tls_servername = "vault-0.vault-internal"
            leader_ca_cert_file = "/vault/userconfig/vault-server-tls-secret/ca.crt"
            leader_client_cert_file = "/vault/userconfig/vault-server-tls-secret/tls.crt"
            leader_client_key_file = "/vault/userconfig/vault-server-tls-secret/tls.key"
          }
        }

        service_registration "kubernetes" {}

        seal "awskms" {
          region     = "${aws_region}"
          kms_key_id = "${kms_key_id}"
        }

injector:
  image:
    repository: ${injector_image_repo}
    tag: 1.0.0
  agentImage:
    repository: ${injector_agent_image_repo}
    tag: 1.11.3
  replicas: 3
  certs:
    secretName: vault-server-tls-secret
  webhook:
    annotations:
      "cert-manager.io/inject-ca-from: vault/vault-server-cert"
    failurePolicy: Fail
    namespaceSelector:
      matchExpressions:
      - key: kubernetes.io/metadata.name
        operator: In
        values: ${webhook_namespace_selector}
```

The annotations added to the sidecar proxy container are as follows:

```
vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject: "true"
vault.hashicorp.com/agent-init-first: "true"
vault.hashicorp.com/tls-secret: vault-server-tls-secret
vault.hashicorp.com/ca-cert: /vault/tls/ca.crt
vault.hashicorp.com/role: x
vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-secret-x: x
vault.hashicorp.com/agent-run-as-user: "2000"
vault.hashicorp.com/agent-run-as-group: "2000"
vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-template-x: |
  xxx
```

I have verified that the certificates match on both the client and server sides. The Helm chart version is 0.25.0, and the Vault application version is 1.14.0.

Comment: check here: https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/docs/platform/k8s/helm/examples/standalone-tls

Comment: what happens when you try exporting  `export VAULT_ADDR='http://127.0.0.1:8200'` and then exporting the root token generated after running this command `vault server -dev` ?
`export VAULT_TOKEN="s.XXXXXX"`

Comment: Vault server is not running on pod's localhost (client). When I change https://vault.vault.svc to http://vault.vault.svc then it works but this is without TLS which I don't want in production scenarios.

Comment: This is kind of odd since TLS is enabled by default, and you are not disabling it in the server config. Is there a conflicting configuration somewhere.

Comment: Yes, I agree it is odd. There is no other potentially conflicting config.